# How to find name of a song from mp3?

Tags: search, mp3

There is a video on YouTube, I like the tune played in the first few seconds, the person who has posted that video has not given details about it, I have recorded it as mp3, I want to find the name and artist of the tune/song.

Which free site is good for finding songs from mp3?

Answer (score 1):

**Shazam** install the app on your phone, play the youtube song to it

Comment: There is also [Google Sound Search](https://support.google.com/googleplaymusic/answer/2913276?hl=en).